# Swift - create Live Photo from mov and jpg file

Tags: ios, swift, apple-live-photos

I would like to create a live photo from mov and jpg files. I found the LivePhoto library https://github.com/LimitPoint/LivePhoto

When I call generate function, I get an error - " Missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call".

```
@IBAction func saveLivePhoto(imageUrl: URL, videoUrl: URL){

    LivePhoto.generate(from: imageUrl, videoURL: videoUrl, progress: { percent in }, completion: { livePhoto, resources in

        LivePhoto.saveToLibrary(resources!)
    })
}
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed to add completion block parameter in LivePhoto.saveToLibrary function call. Try the code below:

```
@IBAction func saveLivePhoto(imageUrl: URL, videoUrl: URL){

        LivePhoto.generate(from: imageUrl, videoURL: videoUrl, progress: { percent in }, completion: { livePhoto, resources in

            LivePhoto.saveToLibrary(resources!) { (bool) in
                
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Your answer solved this problem. But I have another problem.
After calling the function, the application will crash.
I get the error:
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value. Why resources is optional value?

Comment: You have to check that with the library you are using. LivePhotoResources in completion block of generate function is defined as optional only. So if you are not 100% sure that it would not be nil you should not wrap it like resources!. Hope it helps. And if you find the answer helpful, be sure to accept and upvote it so that it would help others too.